# Person with Little Or No Knowledge

Tags: phrase-meaning

Person with Little Or No Knowledge is called what? I want to know one word for this phrase.

Comment: Some synonims : Philistine, Beoetian, illiterate, uneducated, under-educated, weak minded.

Comment: There was a political party in the United States in the 1840s and 1850s—staunchly anti-immigrant and anti-Catholic—whose members were known as the [Know-Nothings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Know_Nothing). Against all odds, no one currently lays claim to the name, so you could use it.

Answer (score 3):

An 'ignoramus' is a person with little or no knowledge.

From the [OED](http://www.oed.com/):

> ignoramus, n.
>
> ....
>
> 2. An ignorant person.

The OED shows 'ignorant' in the sense of 'an ignorant person' as "now rare".

> ignorant, adj. and n.
>
> ....
>
> B. n.
>
> a. An ignorant person. Now rare.

Answer (score 1):

Oxford Advanced Learner’s Dictionary, 8th edition

**ignorant**

1   lacking knowledge or information about sth; not educated 
an ignorant person/question 
  Never make your students feel ignorant. 
~ about sth   He's ignorant about modern technology. 
~ of sth   At that time I was ignorant of events going on elsewhere.

© Oxford University Press, 2010

Answer (score 0):

[layman](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layperson#Professional_context)

> a person without professional or specialized knowledge in a particular subject.

*from a layman's perspective, law seems straightforward, but legal experts appreciate how complex it can be*

Comment: "Layman" is only applicable in this way. Never use "layman" as synonymous with "ignoramus". There are many well-informed laymen; because they lack  specialised or esoteric knowledge does not make them generally ignorant.

Comment: Stylistically, I agree, even if technically, regardless of how well-informed, a layman is still always ignorant of expert knowledge. "Ignorant" is often used to describe with contempt, but words applied contemptuously do not necessarily change their meaning.